# Chrome v91, AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop. Please contact your app vendor

Tags: google-chrome, azure-active-directory, ms-adal-angular

I have a website that uses Azure AD for authentication. It has worked fine for years. But with the most recent release of Chrome (v91), all of our users are now getting the following error:

AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop. Please contact your app vendor.

The web app works fine on other browsers. What changes did Google release that would cause this? Looking for guidance on how to resolve the error with Chrome.

[image: Chrome v91 Azure AD sign in error]

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache: Click the `Ctrl + Shift + Delete` shortcut, and then clear all the content related to the Cookie.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWAwy.png

Comment: @CarlZhao tried, made no difference.

Comment: Please provide more details about your application. Is this a pure spa, or is it backed by a server (and does that server set its own auth cookies)?